# Построение круговой диаграммы

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как бы саму диаграмму реализовать не проблема, благо библиотек много. Но затык в том, что эта диаграмма сама делится ровно на 4 части. Как такое вообще делать?

Comment: Подгоном коэффициентов? Мне кажется, что тут совпадение с делением не 4 части совсем не случайное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логически рассуждая, на диаграмме 4 выборки и 4 сегмента.

Следовательно, надо заполнять сегменты.

Вот пример с библиотекой [chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html) - делаем "пончик" (donut):

```
new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', {
  series: [20, 10, 30, 40]
}, {
  donut: true,
  donutWidth: 130,
  startAngle: 270,
  total: 400,
  showLabel: true
});
```

И так для каждого сегмента, настраивая переменные под ваши размеры и другие параметры. https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#simple-gauge-chart

Можно воспользоваться и другими библиотеками